# How to prevent new opened tab to have content.js from the old tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, code-injection

I'm working on a chrome extension to play or pause a web page's html5 video when I'm on another web page, and I need inject content.js to a new opened tab, the problem I have is the new opened tab have two copies of content.js, one is from the injection when it was created, another one is from the old tab which opened the new tab, that destroys the program's logic, and everything will works fine if I refresh the new opened page. It means that a copy of content.js is disappeared after refreshing the page.

This behavior destroys the my extension's logic totally, how could I stop this from happening ? Is there a configuration in manifest.json could stop an old page from passing it's content.js to the new opened one ?

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Video Controler",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Mute html5 video with shortkey.",
    "permissions": ["nativeMessaging", "debugger", "storage", "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/"],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },
    "page_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "icon/icon16.png",
            "32": "icon/icon32.png",
            "48": "icon/icon48.png",
            "128": "icon/icon128.png"
        }
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "css": ["videoInfo.css"],
            "js": ["content.js"],
            "run_at": "document_start"
        }
    ],
    "commands": {
        "pause" : {
            "suggested_key": {
                "mac": "Command+Shift+Z"
            },
            "description": "Pause video"
        }
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Comment: Declaring "content_scripts" in manifest.json means the script is running automatically so you don't need to inject anything. Can't help further without seeing the actual code.

Comment: You are right @wOxxOm,  at first I needed do it, because there is some code should be executed only once in content.js, bugs would be caused if I don't do it, and then i changed the program logic but i forgot to change the injection part, well now the extension works perfectly after removing the injection, thank you so much !